# Show that $\mu_{F}$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{S})$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{S}=\{A\subseteq \mathbb{R}:$ either $A$ is countable or $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is countable }. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be any function, and define $\mu_{F}:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by

$\mu_{f}(A)=$sup $\{\Sigma_{x\in F}f(x):F\subseteq A$ is finite$\}$ Show that $\mu_{f}$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{S})$.

Now I know that a measure on $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a function $\mu:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ such that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{k})=\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_{k})$, but I am unsure of how to incorporate the disjoint sets into the definition for $\mu_{f}(A)$.
I know that if $E_{1}\cup E_{2}\cup...=A$ where each $E_{i}$ is disjoint then we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mu_{f}(E_{1}\cup E_{2}\cup...)=\mu_{f}(A)&=\text{sup}\{\Sigma_{x\in F}f(x):F\subseteq A \space
 \text{is finite}\}\\
&=\text{sup}\{f(x_{1})+...f(x_{n}):\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}\in F\}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and somehow the last line should equal $\mu_{f}(E_{1})+\mu_{f}(E_{2})+...$ . Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to verify that $\mathcal{S}$ is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra,
so we skip this part. It is also clear that $\mu_{f}(A)\leq\mu_{f}(B)$
whenever $A,B\in\mathcal{S}$ and $A\subseteq B$.

Let $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $A_{i}\cap A_{j}=\emptyset$
whenever $i\neq j$. Let $A=\cup_{i}A_{i}$.

Firstly we go to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i})\leq\mu_{f}(A)$.
If $\mu_{f}(A_{i})=\infty$ for some $i$, then $\infty=\mu_{f}(A_{i})\leq\mu_{f}(A)$
and it follows that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i})=\mu_{f}(A)$.
Suppose that $\mu_{f}(A_{i})<\infty$ for each $i$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be arbitrary. For each $i$, choose a finite set $F_{i}\subseteq A_{i}$
such that $\mu_{f}(A_{i})<\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{i}}+\sum_{x\in F_{i}}f(x)$.
Define $E_{n}=\cup_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}$, then $E_{n}\subseteq A$ and
$E_{n}$ is finite. Therefore $\sum_{x\in E_{n}}f(x)\leq\mu_{f}(A)$
for each $n$. Finally,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i}) & \leq & \varepsilon+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{x\in F_{i}}f(x)\\
 & = & \varepsilon+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{x\in F_{i}}f(x)\right)\\
 & = & \varepsilon+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{x\in E_{n}}f(x)\\
 & \leq & \varepsilon+\mu_{f}(A).
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i})\leq\mu_{f}(A)$.

Next, we go to show that $\mu_{f}(A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i}).$
Let $F\subseteq A$ be an arbitrary finite set. For each $i$, let
$F_{i}=F\cap A_{i}$. Note that $F_{i}=\emptyset$ except for at most
finitely many $i$ because $F_{i}\cap F_{j}=\emptyset$ whenever $i\neq j$
, $F$ is finite, and $F=\cup_{i}F_{i}$. Enumerate $\{i\in\mathbb{N}\mid F_{i}\neq\emptyset\}=\{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{n}\}$.
We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i}) & \geq & \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu_{f}(A_{i_{j}})\\
 & \geq & \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{x\in F_{i_{j}}}f(x)\\
 & = & \sum_{x\in F}f(x).
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i})$ is an upper bound
of $\{\sum_{x\in F}f(x)\mid F\subseteq A\mbox{ and }F\mbox{ is finite.}\}$
and hence $\mu_{f}(A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{f}(A_{i})$.